# Pages library is not getting created when activating publishing feature

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We have created a webtemplate using team site template and we are trying to activate publishing feature. Somehow it's not getting created. Any help is appreciated.

Please check the logs while activating the publishing feature to get pages library in my team site:

> Exception attempting to ApplyWebTemplate to SPSite
>   http://siteurl.com/sites/sitecol1 : Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException
>   ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 0x80131904      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.EnableModuleFromXml(String
>   bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback
>   pModuleContext)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.EnableModuleFromXml(String
>   bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback
>   pModuleContext)     -  -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionModules(SPFeaturePropertyCollection
>   props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags,
>   Boolean fForce)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection
>   props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web,
>   SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb
>   webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags
>   activateFlags, Boolean fForce)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition
>   featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties,
>   SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean
>   fMarkOnly)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid
>   featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version
>   version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties,
>   SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean
>   fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.EnsureFeaturesActivatedCore(SPSite
>   site, SPWeb web, String sFeatures, Boolean fMarkOnly)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.<>c_*DisplayClass7.b*_6()
>   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunAsUser(SPUserToken userToken,
>   Boolean bResetContext, WaitCallback code, Object param)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.EnsureFeaturesActivatedAtWeb(Byte[]&
>   userToken, Guid& tranLockerId, Int32 nZone, Guid databaseid, Guid
>   siteid, Guid webid, String sFeatures)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.ApplyWebTemplate(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32
>   fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32
>   fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate,
>   Int32& plWebTemplateId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.ApplyWebTemplate(String
>   bstrUrl, String bstrWebTemplateContent, Int32
>   fWebTemplateContentFromSubweb, Int32
>   fDeleteGlobalListsWithWebTemplateContent, String& bstrWebTemplate,
>   Int32& plWebTemplateId)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ProvisionWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate
>   webTemplate, String webTemplateToUse, SPFeatureWebTemplate
>   featureWebTemplate)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWeb.ApplyWebTemplate(SPWebTemplate webTemplate)
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages.TemplatePickerUtil.ApplyWebTemplateAndRedirect(SPSiteAdministration
>   siteAdministration, String strWebTemplate, String strRedirect, Boolean
>   bCreateDefaultGroups, Page page, Boolean bDeleteOnError) Attempting to
>   delete the site collection.
>
> And also
>
> Exception in EnsureFeaturesActivatedAtWeb:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException --->
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
>   0x80131904      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.EnableModuleFromXml(String
>   bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback
>   pModuleContext)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequest.EnableModuleFromXml(String
>   bstrSetupDirectory, String bstrFeatureDirectory, String bstrUrl,
>   String bstrXML, Boolean fForceUnghost, ISPEnableModuleCallback
>   pModuleContext)     -  -- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionModules(SPFeaturePropertyCollection
>   props, SPSite site, SPWeb web, SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags,
>   Boolean fForce)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPElementDefinitionCollection.ProvisionElements(SPFeaturePropertyCollection
>   props, SPWebApplication webapp, SPSite site, SPWeb web,
>   SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean fForce)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeature.Activate(SPSite siteParent, SPWeb
>   webParent, SPFeaturePropertyCollection props, SPFeatureActivateFlags
>   activateFlags, Boolean fForce)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternal(SPFeatureDefinition
>   featdef, Version version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties,
>   SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean
>   fMarkOnly)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureCollection.AddInternalWithName(Guid
>   featureId, Int32 compatibilityLevel, String featureName, Version
>   version, SPFeaturePropertyCollection properties,
>   SPFeatureActivateFlags activateFlags, Boolean force, Boolean
>   fMarkOnly, SPFeatureDefinitionScope featdefScope)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.EnsureFeaturesActivatedCore(SPSite
>   site, SPWeb web, String sFeatures, Boolean fMarkOnly)      at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFeatureManager.<>c_*DisplayClass7.b*_6()

Comment: How are you creating the template? What happens? Do you get an error? Are there any odd messages on the pages? You'll need to say more to get good responses.

Comment: What type of web template?

Comment: You've put "sharepoint foundation" in your tags, yet SharePoint Foundation does not support the publishing infrastructure you speak of. What version of SharePoint are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Is it visible if you log on using the farm administrator account?
Make sure you are "checking-in" everything as they will not be visible depending on the user you are logged on as.

Comment: I am trying to access it using it's url and it says page not found.

Comment: Try going into the parent folder and checking to see if it has a little green arrow next to the page name. If so, then you have to click on the little drop down arrow next to it to "check in."

Comment: Also, did you try signing on as the system account? If you sign on with the system account you will be able to see items that are not published or "checked in". You can check in and publish these items using the system account. If not you will need to have access to the parent directory for where your page is stored. For example: http://contoso/Pages/Forms/AllItems.aspx so that you can "check in" the files.

Comment: I am working on sharepoint 2013